VBA Increment string within For Loop
I'm trying to break up a textbox string (serial number) and start with the initial textbox value then increment it by 1 within a For Loop. I cannot figure out how to start with the first string in the textbox THEN increment it up by 1 until the loop ends.
For i = j To countForms
        
        If incSerialCheck = True Then 'Checkbox on userform to increment entered serial number
                serialNum = serialNumber.Value
                lastThree = Right(serialNum, 3)
                LastThreeInt = CInt(lastThree)
                LastThreePlusOne = LastThreeInt + 1
                LastThreePlusOneStr = CStr(LastThreePlusOne)
                NewSerialNumStr = Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) & LastThreePlusOneStr
        Else
            NewSerialNumStr = serialNumber.Value
        End If
Next i 


What do you mean with first string in textbox? The first character? The first "word"?

My apologies for not being clear. The first serial number is typed in the textbox, then I need that as the the first serial # in the loop...then incremented each time till "countForms" is reached. So if the initial value from the textBox is 90027: I need the first number to be 90027...then 90028, 90029, 90030, etc.

It is unclear what you're trying to achieve, and you are spreading the information all over the place. The code by itself doesn't make much sense. Please describe and indicate in the code (with a comment or a via MsgBox or Debug.Print) at which point you'll be doing something with NewSerialNumStr or add more relevant code (perhaps the whole procedure). Also, you never shared what exactly is wrong with your code. Please rethink once more and update your post with all the information.

Increment Trailing Digits

First run the code as is.
Familiarize yourself with the code by modifying the String serial number (SerialString) and the Boolean flag (IncrementSerial) as you see fit.
If the result is satisfactory, apply to your code. Either way, leave a comment.

Sub IncrementTrailingDigits()

    Const RIGHT_DIGITS As Long = 3
    
    ' Retrieve the values from the user form.
    Dim SerialString As String:
    'SerialString = serialNumber.Value ' more readable is e.g. 'txtSerialNum'
    SerialString = "ABC-123-EFG-001" ' or "123001"
    Dim IncrementSerial As Boolean:
    'IncrementSerial = incSerialCheck.Value ' more readable is e.g. 'chkSerialNum'
    IncrementSerial = True
    
    ' Determine the right digits format.
    Dim RDFormat As String: RDFormat = String(RIGHT_DIGITS, "0")
    
    ' Retrieve the left part of the serial string.
    Dim SerialLeft As String:
    SerialLeft = Left(SerialString, Len(SerialString) - RIGHT_DIGITS)
    
    ' Loop.
    
    Dim i As Long, DigitString As String, IsFirstSerialFound As Boolean
    
    For i = 1 To 5
        If IncrementSerial Then
            If IsFirstSerialFound Then ' it's not the first (the flag is set)
                ' Retrieve right (trailing) digits.
                DigitString = Right(SerialString, RIGHT_DIGITS)
                ' Increment right digits.  
                DigitString = Format(CLng(DigitString) + 1, RDFormat)
                ' Rebuild serial number.
                SerialString = SerialLeft & DigitString
            Else ' it's the first; just set the flag (to 'True')
                IsFirstSerialFound = True
            End If
        'Else ' check box is 'False', do nothing
        End If
    
        MsgBox SerialString
       
    Next i

End Sub


Perfect! That is exactly what I needed. Thank you again for the help!!!

Your code is close to complete.

The 1st part of NewSerialNumStr should be Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) instead of Right(..)

If lastThree is 999, the next serial number is 000 (modify as needed, if you have differene biz rules). LastThreePlusOne will be 1000. Use LastThreePlusOneStr = Right(CStr(LastThreePlusOne), 3) to extract the last three digits.


'            serialNum = serialNumber.Value
            serialNum = "9875643"  ' for debugging
            lastThree = Right(serialNum, 3)
            LastThreeInt = CInt(lastThree)
            LastThreePlusOne = LastThreeInt + 1
            LastThreePlusOneStr = Right(CStr(LastThreePlusOne), 3)
            If Len(serialNum) > 3 Then
                NewSerialNumStr = Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) & LastThreePlusOneStr
            Else ' less than 4 digits
                NewSerialNumStr = LastThreePlusOneStr
            End If
            
            Debug.Print serialNum, NewSerialNumStr

Output:
9875643       9875644


Update:

Question:  I need it to start at the initial number for the first loop and then increment up for each loop after.

serialNum = serialNumber.Value
For i = j To countForms        
    If incSerialCheck = True Then 'Checkbox on userform to increment entered serial number
        lastThree = Right(serialNum, 3)
        LastThreeInt = CInt(lastThree)
        LastThreePlusOne = LastThreeInt + 1
        LastThreePlusOneStr = CStr(LastThreePlusOne)
        NewSerialNumStr = Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) & LastThreePlusOneStr
    Else
        NewSerialNumStr = serialNumber.Value
    End If
    serialNum = NewSerialNumStr
    Debug.Print NewSerialNumStr  ' for debugging
Next i 


Thank you for the response. With your suggestion, the number increments once and then repeats so the output is 9875644, 9875644, 9875644, etc. I need it to start at the initial number for the first loop and then increment up for each loop after.

@Mike I’ve updated the script to address your question. However, I’m not entirely sure how you intend to use NewSerialNumStr on the Userform.

Here is some context: I have a function that creates multiple MS Word docs (countForms is how many will be created). I'm exporting textBox fields to each to each doc but some fields need to be incremented (like a serial number) per each doc. That being said, I'm having a hard time adding the (i) variable (in For i = j To CountForms) to the loop for the serial numbers to increment.

Does the updated script solve your matter. If not, you may need to share more code.

Here is a condensed version of what I'm trying to accomplish:
Sub functionFa()
    Dim savePath As String, saveName As String, changeDate As String
    Dim countForms As Integer, i As Integer, j As Integer
    
    Dim serialNum As String, lastThree As String, LastThreePlusOneStr As String
    Dim LastThreeInt As Integer, LastThreePlusOne As Integer, k As Integer
    
    changeDate = dateFA.Value
    changeDate = Replace(changeDate, "/", ".")
        
        Set WordApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
        WordApp.Visible = False
        fileTemplate = Range("A1").Value
        Set WordDoc = WordApp.Documents.Open(fileTemplate)

        If startAt.Value <> "" Then     ‘Start at a number other than 1
            countForms = Val(startAt.Value) + (qtyFA.Value - 1)
            j = startAt.Value
        Else
            countForms = qtyFA.Value
            j = 1
        End If
                
    For i = j To countForms
        
        If incSerialCheck = True Then 'Checkbox on userform to increment entered serial number
            serialNum = serialNumberFAA.Value
            lastThree = Right(serialNum, 3)
            LastThreeInt = CInt(lastThree)
            LastThreePlusOne = LastThreeInt + 1
            LastThreePlusOneStr = CStr(LastThreePlusOne)
            NewSerialNumStr = Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) & LastThreePlusOneStr
        Else
            NewSerialNumStr = SerialNumber.Value
        End If
            serialNum = NewSerialNumStr
            Debug.Print NewSerialNumStr  ' for debugging 
        End If
        
            WordDoc.FormFields(1).Result = formTrackingNumber.Value
            WordDoc.FormFields(3).Result = workOrder.Value      
            WordDoc.FormFields(17).Result = NewSerialNumStr
            WordDoc.FormFields(27).Result = dateFA.Value
  
                If ValidFileName(saveName) Then
                    With WordDoc
                        .SaveAs savePath & "\" & saveName & ".docx"
                    End If
            End If
Next i

    WordDoc.Close
    WordApp.Quit
    Set WordDoc = Nothing
    Set WordApp = Nothing
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True    
End Sub

And this is the section I'm struggling with. I'm trying to get the serial number to increment and inserted into "WordDoc.FormFields(17)" on EACH form created.
 If incSerialCheck = True Then 'Checkbox on userform to increment entered serial number
            serialNum = serialNumberFAA.Value
            lastThree = Right(serialNum, 3)
            LastThreeInt = CInt(lastThree)
            LastThreePlusOne = LastThreeInt + 1
            LastThreePlusOneStr = CStr(LastThreePlusOne)
            NewSerialNumStr = Left(serialNum, Len(serialNum) - 3) & LastThreePlusOneStr
        Else
            NewSerialNumStr = SerialNumber.Value
        End If
            serialNum = NewSerialNumStr
            Debug.Print NewSerialNumStr  ' for debugging 
        End If

I appreciate everyone's help on this, coding I'm very new to and have limited capacity when writing more complicated things. Please excuse my noobness. Please let me know if what I posted isn't clear

Move serialNum = serialNumberFAA.Value to before For.

Not an answer but perhaps helpful. A function I wrote to increment a string.  The increment is defined by the next position in ipAllowedChars.  Character not in ipAllowedChars are ignored.
Have fun
Public Const AlphaNumeric As String = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYXabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
Public Sub testInc()
 Debug.Print "Hello goes to hellp", Inc("Hello")
 Debug.Print "Hellp goes to Hellq", Inc("Hellp")
 Debug.Print "1234 goes to 1239", Inc("1234", "0123495678")
 ' and with wraparound and ignored characters
 Debug.Print " \zzzzz goes to \100000", Inc("\zzzzz")
End Sub

'Increments ipString.
'ipOrderChars sets the order precedence of allowed characters, with precedence represented by the index in ipOrderChars")
    Public Function Inc(ipString As String, Optional ByVal ipAllowedChars As String) As String
        
        Dim myStringLen As Long
        myStringLen = VBA.Len(ipString)
        
        If myStringLen = 0 Then
            Inc = vbNullString
            Exit Function
        End If
        
        ' Define the set of characters which can be incremented
        Dim myAllowedChars As String
        myAllowedChars = VBA.CStr(IIf(VBA.Len(ipAllowedChars) = 0, AlphaNumeric, ipAllowedChars))
        Dim myAllowedLen As Long
        myAllowedLen = VBA.Len(myAllowedChars)
        
        ' set the start position
        '
        Dim myStringIndex As Long
        myStringIndex = myStringLen
        
        ' we have three conditions to manage
        '    * Acharacter is incrementable
        '    * A character rools over, carry is set and current position set to allowed(1)
        '
        Dim myCarry As Boolean
        myCarry = False
        Do
            If myStringIndex > 0 Then
                Dim myChar As String
                myChar = VBA.Mid$(ipString, myStringIndex, 1)
                Dim myAllowedIndex As Long
                myAllowedIndex = VBA.CLng(VBA.InStr(myAllowedChars, myChar))
            End If
            
            If myStringIndex = 0 Then
            '  the last rollover moved past the end of ipstring
            '    so we just prepend the second allowed char and return
            '    we use the seconf becuase the first is presemed to always exist
            '    at the start of a string even if it isn't there
            '
                If myCarry Then
                    Inc = VBA.Mid$(myAllowedChars, 2, 1) & ipString
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Inc = ipString
                    Exit Function
                End If
                '  if the character at ipStringIndex is not a member of the allowed characters
                '    then insert myAllowedchar(1) at ipStringIndex
                '
                   
            ElseIf VBA.InStr(myAllowedChars, myChar) = 0 Then
                If myCarry Then
                    Inc = VBA.Left$(ipString, myStringIndex) & VBA.Mid$(myAllowedChars, 2, 1) & VBA.Mid$(ipString, myStringIndex + 1)
                    Exit Function
                Else
                    Inc = ipString
                    Exit Function
                End If
            
            ElseIf myAllowedIndex = myAllowedLen Then
                '  The current character in ipString will cause a rollover
                '   the current char is replaced my ipAllowedChars(1) and stringindex is decremented
                '   so that the next pass through the loop does the increment
                '
                ' Can't prepend the recieving Mid$ with VBA '
                Mid$(ipString, myStringIndex, 1) = VBA.Mid$(myAllowedChars, 1, 1)
                myStringIndex = myStringIndex - 1
                myCarry = True
                
            Else ' myAllowedIndex < myAllowedLen '
                ' the current character doesn't require a rollover when incremented
                '    so replace the character at ipStringIndex with the next character in ipAllowedChars
                '
                myCarry = False
                myAllowedIndex = myAllowedIndex + 1
                Dim myNewChar As String
                myNewChar = VBA.Mid$(myAllowedChars, myAllowedIndex, 1)
                Mid$(ipString, myStringIndex, 1) = myNewChar
                Inc = ipString
                Exit Function
          
            End If
            
        Loop
        
  
    End Function

